# Can't use Debug with Any CPU in Visual Studio 2017, ntdll.dll Access violation writing location

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2017

i have an issue with my Application. It worked fine till yesterday. When i'm trying to debug my application i'm getting this error:

"Source Not available
Source information is missing from the debug information for this module"

"Unhandled exception at 0x00000000774B69DE (ntdll.dll) in Test.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x0000000000000000."

i found some solutions but it didn't work for me.

I found that if i'm chaning from "Any CPU" to "X86" it's working.

Tried to load my solution in Visual Studio 2015 with "Any CPU" and debug, it's working.

I already Repair my Visual Studio 2017 installation.

Comment: did you make some x86 specific changes ? Maybe rund build clean and then rebuild again?

Comment: From the last time i worked on this project nothing was changed. Yesterday i only run it to debug something.

Comment: to me it looks like there is a project excluded from your build. try to manually delete all bin and obj folders and then build the solution again.

Comment: @Bizhan - i deleted the folder like you said, but i got the same issue.

Comment: could be a bug. visual studio had some problems with x64 architecture in unit tests which was corrected a few months ago. We had to manually set `Test->Processor Arch for AnyCPU projects` to x86

Comment: I also think it's a bug, because i didn't change anything from the last time i worked on it and everything was fine

Comment: What is the structure of the computer with Visual Studio 2017,x86 or x64?Is it same to the computer with Visual Studio 2015?

Comment: @DasiyTianMSFT - My computer is x64 and yes it's the same computer with Visual Studio 2015

Comment: Did it work when you switch to x64 in your visual studio 2017?Any CPU means, it will run as 64-bit on a 64-bit machine and 32-bit on a 32-bit machine.

Comment: No, i have the same issue when switching to x64

Comment: This should explain why you can run on x86 and not on Any CPU. Can you test to run your App on VS2019 to see if it's the same as it was on VS2017?